# I am not Getting ProfileId for Recurring Payment When I call GetTransactionsDetails PayPal Method with TransactionId as a Parameter

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using Paypal `GetTransactionDetails` API in javascript and passing a parameter `TransactionId` but I am not getting `ProfileId` for Recurring Payment in Response. Can anyone help me?